# Trying to get property 'id' of non-object How to fix it?

Tags: laravel

Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: /home/zubair/htdocs/et-solves/cms/resources/views/cms/pages/Industry/include/industry-js.blade.php)

please check erorr
https://flareapp.io/share/Lm8M3jPv#F66

Comment: it must be an array try to dump $industry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this

```
axios.post('{{route('industry.update',[$industry['id']])}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

`$industry` must be `null` or a non-object like an array. Try `dd($industry)` and confirm it.